# Ubuntu 22.04 вылетает на черный экран, не реагирует ни на что, компьютер продолжает работать

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bsod

Данная ошибка происходит постоянно в рандомные моменты времени. Иногда работает виртуалка, иногда компьютер просто запущен. Вылетает либо черный экран, либо все замирает. Прилагаю логи из /var/log/syslog.

[image: Скрин из утилиты Logs]

````
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.portal.IBus' requested by ':1.71' (uid=1000 pid=2696 comm="/usr/bin/ibus-daemon --panel disable " label="unconfined")
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: app-gnome-snap\x2duserd\x2dautostart-2761.scope: Couldn't move process 2761 to requested cgroup '/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-gnome-snap\x2duserd\x2dautostart-2761.scope': No such process
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: app-gnome-snap\x2duserd\x2dautostart-2761.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: No such process
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: app-gnome-snap\x2duserd\x2dautostart-2761.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: app-gnome-user\x2ddirs\x2dupdate\x2dgtk-2743.scope: Couldn't move process 2743 to requested cgroup '/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-gnome-user\x2ddirs\x2dupdate\x2dgtk-2743.scope': No such process
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: app-gnome-user\x2ddirs\x2dupdate\x2dgtk-2743.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: No such process
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: app-gnome-user\x2ddirs\x2dupdate\x2dgtk-2743.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME date & time target.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME maintenance of expirable data target.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME RFKill support target.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME FreeDesktop screensaver target.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME file sharing target.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME smartcard target.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME sound sample caching target.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka at-spi2-registr[2678]: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka gnome-session-binary[2463]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 2771: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 2771 does not exist.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka gnome-session[2463]: gnome-session-binary[2463]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 2771: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Process with ID 2771 does not exist.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started IBus Daemon for GNOME.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka at-spi2-registr[2678]: Unable to register client with session manager
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.IBus'
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started GNOME printer notifications service.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software.1ba7e9af-54d2-4db4-8f48-b3a98e7bf498.scope.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME printer notifications target.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka NetworkManager[860]: <info>  [1668889357.5896] agent-manager: agent[84a0321cc51acac8,:1.96/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka kernel: [   14.589273] audit: type=1400 audit(1668889357.648:79): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2808 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: tmp-snap.rootfs_GeRqvd.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gnome'
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started Portal service (GNOME implementation).
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka rtkit-daemon[1426]: Supervising 10 threads of 6 processes of 2 users.
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka rtkit-daemon[1426]: message repeated 2 times: [ Supervising 10 threads of 6 processes of 2 users.]
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk' unit='xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service' requested by ':1.41' (uid=1000 pid=2608 comm="/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal " label="unconfined")
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Starting Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation)...
Nov 19 23:22:37 ilyaPeka wpa_supplicant[908]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started GNOME color management service.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME color management target.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started GNOME keyboard configuration service.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME keyboard configuration target.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started GNOME Wacom tablet support service.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME Wacom tablet support target.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started GNOME keyboard shortcuts service.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME keyboard shortcuts target.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started GNOME power management service.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME power management target.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME Session.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target GNOME Wayland Session (session: ubuntu).
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Reached target Current graphical user session.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Condition check resulted in GNOME Initial Setup being skipped.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka gsd-media-keys[2706]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-repeat
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka gsd-media-keys[2706]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:hibernate
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Activating service name='org.gnome.ScreenSaver' requested by ':1.70' (uid=1000 pid=2709 comm="/usr/libexec/gsd-power " label="unconfined")
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver'
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka kernel: [   15.515688] audit: type=1326 audit(1668889358.576:80): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=2808 comm="snap-store" exe="/snap/snap-store/599/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7fbb534f873d code=0x50000
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk'
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation).
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop'
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started Portal service.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Startup finished in 3.117s.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: GNOME Shell started at Sat Nov 19 2022 23:22:37 GMT+0300 (MSK)
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: Registering session with GDM
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka gdm-launch-environment]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka gsd-color[2698]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Najing_CEC_Panda_FPD_Technology_CO__ltd_gdm_127
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Consumed 4.119s CPU time.
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1'
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka snapd-desktop-i[2538]: New theme: gtk=Yaru-magenta-dark icon=Yaru-magenta cursor=Yaru, sound=Yaru
Nov 19 23:22:38 ilyaPeka snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[2538]: All available theme snaps installed
Nov 19 23:22:39 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Activating service name='org.gnome.ArchiveManager1' requested by ':1.93' (uid=1000 pid=3038 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
Nov 19 23:22:39 ilyaPeka gdm3: Gdm: Child process -1837 was already dead.
Nov 19 23:22:39 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[859]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.fwupd' unit='fwupd.service' requested by ':1.119' (uid=1000 pid=2808 comm="/snap/snap-store/599/usr/bin/snap-store --gapplica" label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software (enforce)")
Nov 19 23:22:39 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: Starting Firmware update daemon...
Nov 19 23:22:39 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ArchiveManager1'
Nov 19 23:22:39 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
Nov 19 23:22:39 ilyaPeka gnome-shell[2487]: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.2
Nov 19 23:22:39 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[859]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
Nov 19 23:22:39 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: Started Firmware update daemon.
Nov 19 23:22:40 ilyaPeka kernel: [   16.945381] audit: type=1107 audit(1668889360.004:81): pid=859 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.4" pid=2808 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=878 peer_label="unconfined"
Nov 19 23:22:40 ilyaPeka kernel: [   16.945381]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 19 23:22:40 ilyaPeka kernel: [   16.945750] audit: type=1107 audit(1668889360.004:82): pid=859 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.4" pid=2808 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=878 peer_label="unconfined"
Nov 19 23:22:40 ilyaPeka kernel: [   16.945750]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 19 23:22:40 ilyaPeka snap-store[2808]: enabled plugins: fwupd, os-release, packagekit-refine-repos, packagekit-refresh, appstream, hardcoded-blocklist, hardcoded-popular, modalias, packagekit, rewrite-resource, provenance, snap, systemd-updates, generic-updates, provenance-license, icons
Nov 19 23:22:40 ilyaPeka snap-store[2808]: disabled plugins: dpkg, dummy, fedora-langpacks, fedora-pkgdb-collections, repos
Nov 19 23:22:40 ilyaPeka kernel: [   16.947755] audit: type=1107 audit(1668889360.008:83): pid=859 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.4" pid=2808 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=878 peer_label="unconfined"
Nov 19 23:22:40 ilyaPeka kernel: [   16.947755]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 19 23:22:40 ilyaPeka kernel: [   16.947976] audit: type=1107 audit(1668889360.008:84): pid=859 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.4" pid=2808 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=878 peer_label="unconfined"
Nov 19 23:22:40 ilyaPeka kernel: [   16.947976]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 19 23:22:40 ilyaPeka snap-store[2808]: /etc/PackageKit/Vendor.conf file not found
Nov 19 23:22:40 ilyaPeka kernel: [   17.259517] audit: type=1400 audit(1668889360.320:85): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/PackageKit/Vendor.conf" pid=2808 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov 19 23:22:40 ilyaPeka kernel: [   17.561909] audit: type=1400 audit(1668889360.620:86): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/appstream.conf" pid=2808 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov 19 23:22:43 ilyaPeka PackageKit: refresh-cache transaction /364_bdbbeeae from uid 1000 finished with success after 2373ms
Nov 19 23:22:43 ilyaPeka snap-store[2808]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Builder.desktop/* to plugin cache
Nov 19 23:22:43 ilyaPeka snap-store[2808]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Calculator.desktop/* to plugin cache
Nov 19 23:22:43 ilyaPeka snap-store[2808]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.clocks.desktop/* to plugin cache
Nov 19 23:22:43 ilyaPeka snap-store[2808]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Dictionary.desktop/* to plugin cache
Nov 19 23:22:43 ilyaPeka snap-store[2808]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Documents.desktop/* to plugin cache
Nov 19 23:22:43 ilyaPeka snap-store[2808]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Evince/* to plugin cache
Nov 19 23:22:43 ilyaPeka snap-store[2808]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.gedit.desktop/* to plugin cache
Nov 19 23:22:43 ilyaPeka snap-store[2808]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Maps.desktop/* to plugin cache
Nov 19 23:22:43 ilyaPeka snap-store[2808]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Weather/* to plugin cache
Nov 19 23:22:43 ilyaPeka snap-store[2808]: Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
Nov 19 23:22:44 ilyaPeka snapd[886]: storehelpers.go:748: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "bare", "code", "core", "core18", "core20", "firefox", "gnome-3-38-2004", "gtk-common-themes", "snap-store", "snapd", "snapd-desktop-integration", "vlc"
Nov 19 23:22:44 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 23:22:44 ilyaPeka PackageKit: resolve transaction /365_becbacbc from uid 1000 finished with success after 924ms
Nov 19 23:22:45 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
Nov 19 23:22:45 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.100' (uid=1000 pid=3598 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real --wait " label="unconfined")
Nov 19 23:22:45 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Created slice Slice /app/org.gnome.Terminal.
Nov 19 23:22:45 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Nov 19 23:22:45 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Nov 19 23:22:45 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Nov 19 23:22:45 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started VTE child process 3621 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 3603.
Nov 19 23:22:45 ilyaPeka PackageKit: search-file transaction /366_eecdeeac from uid 1000 finished with success after 527ms
Nov 19 23:22:45 ilyaPeka PackageKit: search-file transaction /367_dadadeda from uid 1000 finished with success after 343ms
Nov 19 23:22:46 ilyaPeka PackageKit: search-file transaction /368_ceaccedb from uid 1000 finished with success after 316ms
Nov 19 23:22:46 ilyaPeka PackageKit: get-details transaction /369_dbecebbc from uid 1000 finished with success after 273ms
Nov 19 23:22:48 ilyaPeka nautilus[2659]: Could not delete '.meta.isrunning': No such file or directory
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 127...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped target Main User Target.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka gvfsd[1430]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopping PipeWire Media Session Manager...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopping Tracker file system data miner...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopping flatpak document portal service...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopping sandboxed app permission store...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: xdg-permission-store.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: xdg-permission-store.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped sandboxed app permission store.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped PipeWire Media Session Manager.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: run-user-127-gvfs.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: dbus.service: Killing process 1487 (gmain) with signal SIGKILL.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: xdg-document-portal.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=20/n/a
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: xdg-document-portal.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped flatpak document portal service.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka tracker-miner-fs-3[1463]: OK
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopping PipeWire Multimedia Service...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Removed slice User Core Session Slice.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped Tracker file system data miner.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Removed slice User Background Tasks Slice.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped target Basic System.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped target Paths.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped target Sockets.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Stopped target Timers.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Closed PipeWire Multimedia System Socket.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Closed debconf communication socket.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Closed Sound System.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Removed slice User Application Slice.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Reached target Shutdown.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Finished Exit the Session.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1400]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: user@127.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 127.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: user@127.service: Consumed 1.555s CPU time.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/127...
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: run-user-127-doc.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: run-user-127.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@127.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/127.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 127.
Nov 19 23:22:49 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: user-127.slice: Consumed 5.985s CPU time.
Nov 19 23:22:51 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract' unit='tracker-extract-3.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=1000 pid=2332 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 " label="unconfined")
Nov 19 23:22:51 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Nov 19 23:22:51 ilyaPeka dbus-daemon[2280]: [session uid=1000 pid=2280] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract'
Nov 19 23:22:51 ilyaPeka systemd[2254]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Nov 19 23:22:56 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 19 23:22:58 ilyaPeka systemd-timesyncd[766]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Nov 19 23:22:58 ilyaPeka systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.```
````

Comment: Возможно плохой блок питания. Отвалился хард от этого и оно зависло... Бывает

Comment: @eri а как это проверить? Есть возможность программно диагностировать или только в сервис нести?

Comment: Видеокарта перегревается?

Comment: @user_587, нет, с ней все в порядке.